# Is it possible to change the Boot Camp language?

Tags: mac, boot-camp

Is it possible to switch to or manually download and install the English version of Boot Camp 4 for Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install another version, with the language that you want.  You can not change the language from within Boot Camp.